# How can i delete an experience view from salesforce?

Tags: vs-code, experience-cloud, digital-experience

i have a problem that i can't retrieve experience bundle due to a json view that generates errors , so i have to delete that view so that i can retrieve the code from the sandbox .

i had many searches but i don't know how to find a way to that view because the view is deleted from the builder but still somewhere in the code .

[image: The error while trying to retreive the code]

Comment: Can you share the json snippet

Comment: You could also try to move the bundle via change set, maybe the deployment to sandbox will fail and tell you some more details.

Comment: Hey Damecek , thanks for the reply ,   i can't retreive the json  because of that error i don't know how to get it from inside the org , tried the package xml but still the same problem . Do you know any solution i'm really stuck  ?

Comment: ha, right :D, you can try to remove one component at a time and try to retrieve, this way you can find the one which causes trouble.

Comment: same problem :/ i even tried to retreive with workbench or ant but i can't that's strange 
i can't modify or get this experience bundle

Comment: Could this be related to [KI](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000000sck5QAA)?

Comment: i already check it and no result :/